# Regex to match date with a space

Tags: regex

I currently have the following regex to match a date:

```
([012]?\d)[\/.-]([0123]?\d)[\/.-]([012]\d{3})\b
```

This will match, for example `12/24/2011`. How would I make the regex so it also matches with a space between the items, `12 24 2011`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your questions has been already answered, but I see some other issues with your regex.

1. Why do have the word boundary only at the end? You should also use it at the start.
2. Your regex would also match things like "1.3/2012". You can imporve this easily by using a backreference.
3. Do you need all those capturing groups?

So my suggestion would be this

```
\b([012]?\d)([\/. -])([0123]?\d)\2([012]\d{3})\b
            ^^^^^^^^^           ^^
         store the first       match
         occurence in          group 2
         group 2
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?30mo2)

Answer (score 4):

Add the space character in the character class:

```
[\/. -]
    ^
```

Comment: For that I would get 'NO MATCHES. CHECK FOR DELIMITER COLLISION.' It could just be the program I was checking in though (http://myregextester.com/index.php)

Comment: Don't you need to use `\s` for space?

Comment: @David542 Escape the dash or change the position of the dash and the space `[\/. -]`, because the dash has a special meaning inside a character class. This `[\/.- ]` is creating a character range from . to space in the ASCII table. If the space is before the dot (I haven't checked) this could cause an error.

Comment: @Jack `\s` is a whitespace character and not only a space. This will also match a tab or a newline or probably also some more obscure whitespace characters.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
([012]?\d)[ \/.-]([0123]?\d)[ \/.-]([012]\d{3})\b
```

I think that you must add spaces first.

Answer (score 0):

```
([012]?\d)([\/.-]|\s)([0123]?\d)([\/.-]|\s)([012]\d{3})\b
```

Answer (score 0):

```
([012]?\d)[\/.-\s]([0123]?\d)[\/.-\s]([012]\d{3})\b
```